# glStencilOp -- GL_INCR_WRAP GL_DECR_WRAP. stencil mask behaviour

Tags: opengl

OpenGL documentation for glStencilOp isn't clear on what happens for increment and decrement operations in the presence of stencil masks.  It seems to imply that the mask will be ignored for increment and decrement operation.

Can anyone confirm/refute that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The mask will not be ignored. Instead, the increment or decrement operation is performed as though there was no mask, but the only bits in the stencil buffer that will be set to the incremented value are those allowed by the mask.

Comment: so, if certain upper bits are masked out, then neither of the "wrap" operations will ever really wrap...

Comment: Or, if you look at it another way, they'll wrap sooner. If you consider a hypothetical 8-bit stencil, with a mask on the high 4 bits, and use `GL_INCR_WRAP`, a value of 15 (`00001111`) will be incremented to 16 (`00010000`) and immediately be masked down to zero, wrapping faster.